# How to make yandex translator api work with raspberry pi

Tags: python

I want to make a python script such that it takes english text from a normal txt file and convert it into another language and store the output in seperate txt file. I have a RPI 3B

I have a text file in English stored in a .txt file. I want to know how to attach that .txt files data to the 'text' part of the API.

Comment: I think this is probably a little too broad for our format. You should [edit] with specifically are you struggling with, so we can give you specific help. Is a specific piece of code not working? Are you just stuck on how to get started at all?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should explain what you have tried and how you have failed.

## Install [python-yandex-translate](https://github.com/dveselov/python-yandex-translate)

```
pip install yandex.translate
```

python code:

```
from yandex_translate import YandexTranslate
translate = YandexTranslate('Your API key here.')
print('Languages:', translate.langs)
print('Translate directions:', translate.directions)
print('Detect language:', translate.detect('Привет, мир!'))
print('Translate:', translate.translate('Привет, мир!', 'ru-en'))  # or just 'en'
```